# Horizontal Scroll Bar on DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Is there a way to have the horizontal scroll bar while having the AutoSizeMode for the column set to fill?

I have 2 columns, and I want them to fill the width of the DataGridView. When the width of content in the rows exceed the width of the DataGridView, I want to enable the horizontal scroll bar. Not sure how to do this. With the research I have done, I found that using the "AllCell" option in the AutoSizeMode would enable the scroll bar, however, I want the rows to fill the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both behaviors natively.
You will have to code it using `DataGridViewColumn.MinimumWidth` property.
Here is an example using `DataGridView`'s `CellValueChanged` event (but you will certainly have to adapt it to your specific case) :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        column.MinimumWidth = column.Width;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
}
```

Be careful, this can be very time consuming if you have lots of rows in your datagrid.

Comment: I was afraid that was the only way to do it. I'll have to do some testing to see how slow it can get. Thanks for the response.

Comment: `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells` can help you if it is too slow, but you will have to override the `Scroll` event too.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way around it, although it obviously isn't ideal:

- add an empty collumn with AutoSizeMode set to Fill at the end
- and set HeaderText of the last column to an empty string (which I obviousy forgot to do in my demo...)

This way it (almost) appears as if the AutoSizeMode  of the 2nd column is set to FIll.

Here, Column1 and Column2 have AutoSizeMode set to DisplayedCells, Column3 to Fill:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old post, but thought I would add to it. If you are not bothered by setting AutoSizeMode to Fill.

Set the AutoSizeMode of the problematic column to AllCells.

This will resize the column header and force it to go out of the visible area thus displaying the horizontal scrollbar.